# Press twice or more to turn off, once to turn on

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm trying to make this sensor in ESP32, and I can't figure out what am I missing or if I did something wrong, I think I could use a relay module to make it easier, but the task implies that I only use basic code like if, while, etc. The thing is that I need to press twice in a short amount of time (1 or 2 seconds) while it is on to turn it off, and if it is off, just press once and it will turn on. I can't figure out how to make the sensor to stop, since it keeps giving signals.
It should work like: when someone goes closer than 30cm to the sensor, the red LED blink, if not the green LED is always on. I need to put in a button that turns off and on this device.

I tried to create a parameter that tells if it is on or off, but I can't make it work, I can not figure out why tho.

```
`#include <Arduino.h>
    #define trigger 27
#define echo 14
#define ledrojo 4
#define ledverde 5
#define BOTON 13
float distancia = 0;
unsigned long ta = 0;
unsigned long tiempo_capturado_inicio = 0;
unsigned long tiempo_pulsado = 0;
int pulsos = 0;
int estadosistema = 0;
byte aux_boton = 0;
byte aux_inicio = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // El numero serial para la comunicacion serial
  pinMode(BOTON, INPUT_PULLUP);
  estadosistema = 0;
}

void loop()
{
  if (!digitalRead(BOTON)) // Cuando se presione el boton
  {
    while (!digitalRead(BOTON))
    {
    }                      // Mientras mantengo el boton presionado, no pasara nada
    aux_inicio = 1;        // Con esto enciendo el temporizador
    aux_boton = 1;         // Con esto comienza el contador
    if (estadosistema = 1) // Si el sistema esta encendido sucedera:
    {
      if (aux_inicio = 1)
      {
        if (millis() - tiempo_pulsado >= 4000) // Tiempo maximo para dar el segundo pulso es 1 segundo
        {
          aux_inicio = 0; // Apagar el temporizador
          aux_boton = 0;  // Apagar el contador
        }
        if (!digitalRead(BOTON))
        {
          aux_boton = 1; // Mantener el contador encendido
        }
        if (aux_boton = 1 && !digitalRead(BOTON)) // Conteo de pulsos
        {
          pulsos += 1;
          aux_boton = 0;
        }
      }
      if (aux_inicio = 0) // Cuando el temporizador termina, se contea los pulsos
      {
        if (pulsos >= 1) // Si se pulso una segunda vez o mas, el sistema se apagara
        {
          estadosistema = 0;
          pulsos = 0;
          aux_boton = 0;
          aux_inicio = 0;
          Serial.print("Se ha apagado el sistema de alarma");
        }
        else
        { // Si solo se presiono una vez, el sistema seguira encendido
          Serial.print("El sistema de alarma sigue encedido");
        }
      }
    }
    if (estadosistema = 0) // Si el sistema esta apagado sucedera:
    {
      estadosistema = 1; // Se enciende el sistema
      delay(1000);
      aux_boton = 0;
      aux_inicio = 0;
      Serial.print("El sistema de alarma se ha encendido");
    }
  }
  if (estadosistema = 0) // Mientras el sistema esta apagado
  {
    distancia = 1000000000000000;
    digitalWrite(trigger,LOW);
    digitalWrite(echo,LOW);
  }
  if (estadosistema = 1)
  {
    pinMode(echo, INPUT);
    // Esto es para recibir la informacion del echo del sensor ultrasonico
    pinMode(trigger, OUTPUT);
    // Esto es lo que provocara una señal en el sistema serial
    pinMode(ledrojo, OUTPUT);
    // Este es el led rojo que se usara cuando haya peligro
    pinMode(ledverde, OUTPUT);
    // Este es el led verde que se usara cuando no haya peligro
    digitalWrite(trigger, HIGH); // Prendemos el trigger
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigger, LOW); // Apagamos el trigger

    ta = pulseIn(echo, HIGH); // Tiempo que demora en llegar la señal al Echo
    ta = ta / 2;
    distancia = ta / 29; // Distancia hasta el obstaculo
    if (distancia <= 30)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledrojo, HIGH);          // Prendemos el LED rojo
      digitalWrite(ledverde, LOW);          // Apagamos el LED verde
      Serial.print("¡PELIGRO, RETROCEDA!"); // Mensaje de que una persona esta en la zona de peligro
      delay(5);
      Serial.print("");
      digitalWrite(ledrojo, LOW); // Hacemos que parpadee a 100Hz
      delay(5);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(ledverde, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(ledrojo, LOW);
    }
  }
}
`
```

Comment: it is not clear which part of this trivial task you don't understand. please share your  code so we can see where you struggle. also it is not clear what sensor and what kind of signal you are referring to. the condition to turn off is quite simple: is it on and is the time difference between the first and the second button press short enough?

Comment: Probably `if (aux_inicio = 0) ` does not compile to what you think. (There are more such issues)

Answer (score 0):

use easyButtton library (look at https://github.com/evert-arias/EasyButton)

try this sketch (may need some fix - not tested)

```
#include <EasyButton.h>

//syntax EasyButton button(BUTTON_PIN, debounce, pullup, invert);
EasyButton button(BOTON, 10, true, false);
boolean sensor_on;
#define trigger 27
#define echo 14
#define ledrojo 4
#define ledverde 5
#define BOTON 13

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // El numero serial para la comunicacion serial
  pinMode(BOTON, INPUT_PULLUP);

  button.begin();
  button.onPressed(buttonPressed);              //single press
  button.onSequence(2, 500, sequenceEllapsed);  //2 press in 500mS - change value if needed
  
  if (button.supportsInterrupt())
  {
    button.enableInterrupt(buttonISR);
    wifi.sendNow("Button will be used through interrupts");
  }
  
}
  
void loop() {

//button.read(); //remove comment if button don't work by interrupt

if(sensor_on) {  //1 press
  if(get_distance() < 30) { 
   blink_red_led();             //red led blink
   digitalWrite(ledverde, LOW); //green led off
   } else {
   digitalWrite(ledverde, HIGH);//green led on
   digitalWrite(ledrojo,LOW);   //red led off
   } 
  } else {  //no measure and set all leds off
   digitalWrite(ledverde, LOW);
   digitalWrite(ledrojo,LOW);
  }
}

ICACHE_RAM_ATTR void buttonISR() {
  button.read();
}
    
void buttonPressed() {
sensor_on=true;
}

void sequenceEllapsed() {
sensor_on=false;
}

unsigned long get_distance() {
 digitalWrite(trigger, HIGH); // Prendemos el trigger
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(trigger, LOW); // Apagamos el trigger
 
 unsigned long ta = pulseIn(echo, HIGH); // Tiempo que demora en llegar la señal al Echo
 ta = ta / 2;
 return(ta / 29); // Distancia hasta el obstaculo
}  

void blink_red_led() {
 digitalWrite(ledverde, LOW);
 digitalWrite(ledrojo, !digitalRead(ledrojo);
 delay(200);
}
```